# When reducing a matrix using Gauss Jordan reduction, why are the corresponding elementary matrices acting on rows multipled together in reverse order?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a hard time explaining this problem so I think I'll let this youtube link do the talking.

https://youtu.be/-voH_B21eXc?t=1177

In this link, you could see that he's trying to reduce a matrix to echelon form. However, he mentions that to get P, he has to multiply the reduction matrices from right to left order. I understand that matrix multiplication isn't commutative, so how does that factor into why the order multiplication is reversed from the order of row operations?

Comment: They aren't reversed. Think about function composition: when we write $f\circ g\circ h$, we do $h$ **first**, $g$ *second*, and $f$ last. Same thing here.

Comment: What is the connection between each row operation and function composition?

Comment: The elementary matrices are like functions actung on the matrix. The effect of the product *is* to perform the elementary row operation. So you can think of the product as the application of a function on the matrix... because that is *exactly* what it is.

Answer (score 1):

If $E$ is the elementary matrix associated with a row operation, then we apply this operation to a matrix $M$ by computing the product $EM$. If we want to apply two row operations with associated matrices $E_1,E_2$ to a matrix $M$, we apply the first operation by computing $E_1M$ and apply the second operation to this result by computing
$$
E_2(E_1 M) = (E_2E_1)M.
$$
Concordantly, applying $n$ operations with associated matrices $E_1,\dots,E_n$ is the same as computing the product
$$
E_n(\cdots(E_2(E_1 M))\cdots) = (E_n \cdots E_2 E_1) M.
$$